# Nativescript Missing Dashed Border

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I am looking for a `border-style: dashed;` styling option for stack layouts. But I don't see any support for it. How can I create a dashed border style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NativeScript supports a subset of CSS. That said some of the CSS used in web is not applicable. As of this moment, the border in NativeScript does not support border-style property.

Source: https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/3246

In order to achieve dashed border use a dash image with background repeat.

Comment: The dash hack in that question isn't working for me, I'm using nativescript angular.

Comment: I'm not sure which hack from which question you are referring to, but I would like to clarify there is nothing specific to flavour (Core / Angular / Vue), the syntax may be different but the feature set is mostly same. As I proposed, using a background image with repeat true should work on any flavour.